# Django Import-Export User Foreignkey & M2M Import Logic Check

Tags: django, postgresql, csv, import, django-import-export

**Web Logic**

1. A user creates a new Trade object (enters data like Symbol, Broker, Notes, etc.)
2. Trade is still empty
3. The user creates entries now for this trade (ex. 100 shares @ $5 buy)
4. Trade must have at least 2 Entires to be a closed trade
5. Entries are added on the same form page as create trade using inlineformset_factory

**Model.py**

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='cl')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=LONG)
    broker = models.ForeignKey(Broker, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, default=DEFAULT_ASSET_ID, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Symbol, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    patterns = models.ManyToManyField(Pattern, blank=True)
    notes = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    associated_portfolios = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(default='no-image-available-icon.jpg', upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)

  
class Entry(models.Model):
    trade = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    fee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    entry_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES, default=ENTRY)
    reg_fee = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Example CSV Data** (I added space instead of "," to show data easier)

```
Date/Time               Description                 Amount  Commission  RegFee  NetCashBalance  
07/17/2020 7:42:39      Bought 40 APDN @ 14.56      -582.4      0       0       25,755.84
07/17/2020 7:47:16      Bought 40 APDN @ 14.78      -591.2      0       0       25,164.64
07/17/2020 7:53:36      Bought 20 APDN @ 14.27      -285.4      0       0       24,879.24
07/17/2020 8:04:01      Bought 100 VRNA @ 9.58      -958        0       0       23,921.24
07/17/2020 8:05:01      Bought 20 VRNA @ 9.47       -189.4      0       0       23,731.84
07/17/2020 8:05:27      Sold 21 APDN @ 14.885       312.58      0       0.01    24,044.42
07/17/2020 8:05:27      Sold 79 APDN @ 14.87        1,174.69    0       0.04    25,219.11
07/17/2020 8:06:43      Sold 120 VRNA @ 10.08       1,209.56    0       0.04    26,428.67
```

If it hasn't hit you yet based on the CSV file that the broker exports this is going to be a super messy procedure where we need to disect a lof of data, match it properly, create new objects, and create multiple new forieng key objects based on newly created objects.

**CSV Import Logic**

To save time it's better the user just imports trade data their broker provides them. Here's an [example site](https://www.tradervue.com/help/generic) (not my project) that does it as well.

```
1. Create an Entry class object (user may need to manually make csv file for cleaner data import)
2. find Trade object where Status == Open and symbol == symbol
3. if step 2 == None then create a new Trade class & assign status to open
4. Def & set Set Symbol_Share_Count == 0
5. Increment or Decrease Symbol_Share_Count by shares
6. Once Symbol_Share_Count == 0 close the trade

3. if step 2 retuns a Trade object then..
4. Def & set Set Symbol_Share_Count == "# of total open shares"
5. Increment or Decrease Symbol_Share_Count by shares of newly imported transaction
6. Once Symbol_Share_Count == 0 close the trade

7. At this point the new or found Trade object is done and a new Trade object can be created or found based on the next transaction
```

Does this logic make sense? Is there a serious issue I am overlooking?

Any feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few logical steps during import, but `django-import-export` provides logical hooks you can use to manage the update of related objects.  The [documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html) lists all of these.

For example, if you use [`after_save_instance()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.after_save_instance), then you can make any logical changes required after the successful persistence of an uploaded object.

You can run the entire import in a transaction if required.

Some other points you may want to consider:

1. If users import a lot of data, you will be tying up a thread on the webserver, and potentially risking time-outs.  This will be ok for small uploads, but for larger uploads, you will want to run the import asynchronously.  [Celery](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/celery.html) might help here.
2. What happens if the import process crashes halfway through?  Can you cleanly rollback? ([Transactions](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_workflow.html#transaction-support) will help here).
3. What happens if the user uploads the same file twice?  They may well do this if their connection drops.  Will your import process avoid creating duplicates? Think of the logic required to make the process idempotent.  You can write your own logic to [skip duplicates](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.skip_row)
4. Are there any ordering concerns?  Does File A need to be imported before File B?
5. Will the process handle multiple simultaneously uploads?  Transactions and updates to multiple objects can run the risk of deadlock.

You may want to consider a batch processing framework to address some of the issues above.  In other words, once the file is uploaded, the batch process will handle the import independently of the web server.  This is obviously more work, but will provide a more robust solution.

Comment: Still working this question out, will comment with more info as soon as I can. Big thanks already for the in-depth response!

Comment: Hey I'm still stuck on this one. Been trying a lot with after_save_instance but thinking I need to maybe use after_import_row to count how many shares a stock has had so I can create a new trade object once the count is back to 0. I'll amend my question soon with an attempt but maybe you have an idea how to create a new trade object based on some simple entry math?

Comment: I would suggest post a new question (rather than amend this one) because this question might help future users.  If the math is based on a single row, [this](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#dynamic-columns) might help.